# Android .xml designing

Tags: android, xml

There has been a flaw on my design for most of .xml files where the sizes usually goes larger on some screens and some on lower screens. I use px(Pixels).

I know that this might be a bad choice on my end because new phones will end up with more pixel ratio. eg Samsung Galaxy Nexus making all text into tiny text.

What would be a far more suitable type to use for future phones to come?

Extra:

I have been using linear layout for a long time but now that I need a scrolling for long menu I designed a RelativeLayout that nested a ScrollView which ScrollView nests a linear layout. Would it be a better Option to nest a tableLayout to have more control over the view?

Didn't want to flood the question screen cause it would look ugly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tab_tv_one"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/auto_Action"
                android:background="#666666"
                android:text="@string/options_dialog_menu_Action"
                android:textSize="27px"
                 />

            <RadioGroup 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/FirstOption"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/manual_Action"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tab_tv_one"
                android:text="@string/options_dialog_menu_Auto_Action"

                android:textSize="27px" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/SecondOption"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tab_tv_two"
                android:layout_below="@+id/auto_Action"
                android:text="@string/options_dialog_menu_Manual_Action"
                android:textSize="27px" 
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:clickable="true"

                />

             <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/ThirdOption"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/tab_tv_two"
                android:layout_below="@+id/manual_Action"
                android:textSize="27px" 
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:clickable="true"

                />

            </RadioGroup>



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tab_tv_two"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/text_size"
                android:layout_below="@+id/manual_Action"
                android:background="#666666"
                android:text="@string/options_dialog_menu_Layout_Options"
                android:textSize="27px"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_size"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/background_clr"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tab_tv_two"
                android:text="@string/options_dialog_menu_Text_Size"
                android:textSize="27px"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:clickable="true"

                 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Options_clr"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/brightness_ctrl"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_size"
                android:text="@string/options_dialog_menu_Color_Options"
                android:textSize="27px"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:clickable="true"

                 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/brightness_ctrl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/background_clr"
                android:text="@string/options_dialog_menu_Brightness_color"
                android:textSize="27px"
                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:clickable="true"

                 />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/backToBasics"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/brightness_ctrl"
                android:text="@string/options_dialog_menu_Back_To_Basics"
                android:textSize="27px"

                android:onClick="onClick"
                android:clickable="true"
                 />


    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think you need to use dp instead of pixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use pixels, use dp (aka dip aka density independent pixels). Otherwise, as you noted, size will be dependent on density, which isn't good.

Its not just the galaxy nexus, ldpi phones will look different than mdpi, which will look different than hdpi etc. There is rarely any good reason to use px sizes, particularly with regards to view dimensions.

With regards to your extra question it depends entirely on what you want your layout to look like. Without seeing code and/or at least knowing what you want to occur (vs what you see now), no one is going to really be able to answer that.

Comment: I will add the code. Didn't want to flood the question screen too much.

Comment: So other than changing pixels to dp (which will be a pain but totally worth it) you aren't doing anything unreasonable. Unless you're having trouble getting the layout to look the way you want it to, just leave it as is. If you find you need features in the tablelayout, there isn't any reason not to use it that i can see, and you can always switch later when you actually need it.